# Jenkins- Build Date in Jenkins Email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have  Jenkin’s “BUILD_ID” env variable redefined using  zentimestamp plugin in my Jenkins setup and I use it in the configured jobs for various reasons. I’m now trying to display the build date in the format “YYYY-MM-DD” in emails triggered by email extn plugin as part of post build. Can anyone direct me how can I display the build date in the above format in emails. I could not use none other Jenkins env variables. Please share your thoughts to get this done or put me in some directions. Thanks.

Comment: You could not use env variables or you were unable to use env variables? Isn't e-mail-ext sending e-mail right after the build has finished? E-mail receival date is already the build date. Anyway, please explain what you are trying to achieve and elaborate which date do you want. The build start, build end or something else?

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you have zentimestamp  plugin installed.
There if you check this option "Change date pattern for the BUILD_TIMESTAMP (build timestamp) variable"

You can then edit the desired date pattern as yyyy-mm-dd.

Now use $BUILD_TIMESTAMP in your Email-ext plugin.

please let me know if it works.